# Allow connections only by client with certificates signed by organizational CA

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, verification

I have OpenSSL server and client.

Server allows connections only with one certificate by function `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, cert, NULL)`, but it is not enough. I want to enable connections for all clients with certificate with was signed by organizational CA.

What should I use?

I have read about set path to folder with "good" client certificates, but it's actually not what I want and it's not working for me too.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is easy, but it is also radically wrong. You are conflating authentication, which is a PKI function based on trusted certificate chains, with authorization, which is an application responsibility. Don';t use mechanisms designed for one purpose for a completely separate purpose.

Comment: @EJP - I understand *"Authentication is not Authorization"*, but I don't see where Vladislav is making that leap. Also, authenticating the user at channel setup provides mutual authentication and channel binding. They are usually desirable properties and a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

> `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, cert, NULL)`... I want to enable connections for all clients with certificate with was signed by organizational CA.
>
> What should I use?

On the server, you need to call `SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list` to have the server send the CA list (and trigger the client). In your case, the list is one CA - the organization's CA or a subordinate CA within the organization.

You can find the OpenSSL man page at [`SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list.html). Its also discussed on the  [`SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html) man page.

---

Here's how to ***find*** an example of using it (OpenSSL is famous for self documenting code):

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.2a
$ grep -R SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list * | grep -v doc
...
apps/s_server.c:    SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, SSL_load_client_CA_file(CAfile));
...
```

Here's how OpenSSL uses it `apps/s_server.c`:

```
char* caFile = NULL;
...

else if (strcmp(*argv, "-CAfile") == 0) {
    caFile = *(++argv);
...

if ((!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, caFile, caPath)) ||
    (!SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx))) {
        ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
}
...

if (caFile != NULL) {
    SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, SSL_load_client_CA_file(caFile));
```

You can find the man pages for [`SSL_load_client_CA_file(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_load_client_CA_file.html).

---

Related, on the OpenSSL mailing list: [Does `STACK_OF(X509_NAME)` need to be free'd when using `SSL_load_client_CA_file?`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.openssl.users/L4Nh_XrhfDk/Ros1VB2ZUJAJ)

---

Assuming your organization PKI looks something like so:

```
                     ++++++++++++++++
                     + Organization +
                     +    Root CA   +
                     ++++++++++++++++
                            |
        +-------------------+------------------+
        |                   |                  |
+--------------+    +--------------+   +--------------+
|  Client Auth |    | Server Auth  |   |  Other ...   |
|    Sub CA    |    |    Sub CA    |   |    Sub CA    |
+--------------+    +--------------+   +--------------+
```

You probably want to send the `Client Authentication` subordinate CA. That limits damage in case something happens in one of the other CA arcs.

The problem case is that of Diginotar, where the Root CA becomes compromised. In that case, you need to burn the entire PKI to the ground and start over.

The subordinate CAs will have `basicConstraint=critical, CA=true`. But they will *not* be self signed. Rather, they will be signed  or certified by the `Organizational Root CA`.

Comment: I generated certificates like this [dst.lbl.gov/~boverhof/openssl_certs.html](http://dst.lbl.gov/~boverhof/openssl_certs.html). Server runs on server.key and server.pem. I pass ca.pem to SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(3) like this [pastebin.com/XpJmXwf6](http://pastebin.com/XpJmXwf6). Am i doing everything correctly?

Comment: @Vladislav - No, that's not correct. You need a `STACK_OF(X509_NAME)`, not `STACK_OF(X509)`. See the edit above.