# Client certificates and mutual authentication in Python

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, twisted

I am trying to make a setup based on [Use TLS and Python for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677455/use-tls-and-python-for-authentication) with proper key authentication.

After a few days of attempting to set up proper ssl certs i get this error.

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE', 'no certificate returned')]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py:614:_doReadOrWrite
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py:215:doRead
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py:221:_dataReceived
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py:419:dataReceived
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py:358:_flushReceiveBIO
]
```

From the output of this from the server:

```
def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print reason
```

I'm not really sure where i'm going wrong in the generation of certs.

This is my code for creating a Certificate authority

```
##------------------------------ Creating CA -------------------------------##
cd /etc/ssl
mkdir CA
cd CA

## Make storage dirs
mkdir certs crl newcerts private

## fix permissions and create directories
chmod 700 private
touch index.txt
echo 1000 > serial

## Create a private key
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out /etc/ssl/CA/private/ca.key.pem 4096
## pass = nill
##/etc/ssl/CA/private/ca.key.pem

chmod 400 /etc/ssl/CA/private/ca.key.pem

## change stuff in ssl config file
nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
###
dir             = /etc/ssl/CA           # Where everything is kept
## Left out
##keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
####


##Self sign CA's certificate
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key /etc/ssl/CA/private/ca.key.pem -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -out /etc/ssl/CA/certs/ca.cert.pem


###
US
AZ
AZ
Nameless CA
Certificate Authority
Nameless CA
3Nameless22222@Nameless.com
###

## This is the CA's public key
chmod 444 /etc/ssl/CA/certs/ca.cert.pem
cp /etc/ssl/CA/certs/ca.cert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/ca.cert.pem

## Join ca.cert.pem and ca.key.pem into a file named ca.private.cert.pem
## in /etc/ssl/private/ca.private.cert.pem
##---------------------------- Creating CA END -----------------------------##
```

Servers Key

```
##-------------------------- Creating Server Key ---------------------------##
cd /etc/ssl/CA

##Create private key for server
openssl genrsa -out private/servermain.key.pem 4096
chmod 400 private/servermain.key.pem


##Create signing request
cd /etc/ssl/CA
openssl req -sha256 -new -key private/servermain.key.pem \
    -out certs/servermain.csr.pem


Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:US
State or Province Name (full name) []:AZ
Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:AZ
Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:Nameless CA
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Certificate Authority
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:mainserver
Email Address []:3Nameless22222@Nameless.com
###

cd /etc/ssl/CA

## Sign servers signing request
openssl ca -keyfile private/ca.key.pem -cert certs/ca.cert.pem \
    -extensions usr_cert -notext -md sha256 \
    -in certs/servermain.csr.pem -out certs/servermain.cert.pem
chmod 444 /etc/ssl/CA/certs/nill.cert.pem

## Join servermain.cert.pem and servermain.key.pem into a file named
## server.pem in /etc/ssl/private/server.pem

##------------------------ Creating Server Key End -------------------------##
```

Client cert creation:

```
##------------------------ Create New Client Certs -------------------------##
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
from twisted.internet.ssl import PrivateCertificate, KeyPair, DN
def getCAPrivateCert():
    #path to a private key
    ## needs to be the path to a CA's private key for signing
    privatePath = FilePath(b"/etc/ssl/private/cacert.pem")
    if privatePath.exists():
        return PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(privatePath.getContent())
    else:
        print "CRASH TIME"

def clientCertFor(name):
    signingCert = getCAPrivateCert()
    clientKey = KeyPair.generate(size=4096)
    csr = clientKey.requestObject(DN(CN=name), "sha1")
    clientCert = signingCert.signRequestObject(
        csr, serialNumber=1, digestAlgorithm="sha1")
    return PrivateCertificate.fromCertificateAndKeyPair(clientCert, clientKey)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    name = sys.argv[1]
    pem = clientCertFor(name.encode("utf-8")).dumpPEM()
    FilePath(name.encode("utf-8") + b".client.private.pem").setContent(pem)
##---------------------- Create New Client Certs End -----------------------##
```

Creating Server

```
##--------------------------------- Server ---------------------------------##
## Note: server.pem is the servers certificate joined with the public key
## servermain.key.pem
## servermain.cert.pem
## ca.cert.pem is the CA's public certificate
from twisted.python.filepath import FilePath
from twisted.internet.endpoints import SSL4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet.ssl import PrivateCertificate, Certificate
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
CERTFILE = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca.cert.pem"
SERVERCERT = "/etc/ssl/private/server.pem"

class ReportWhichClient(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "****************** NEW PEER REQUEST ******************"

        ## Get peer cert id
        peerCertificate = Certificate.peerFromTransport(self.transport)
        userkey = peerCertificate.getSubject().commonName.decode('utf-8')
        print userkey

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connected"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print reason

def main(reactor):
    print "react"

    #Path to CA public key
    cacert = FilePath(CERTFILE).getContent()

    #Path to Server private key
    pemBytes = FilePath(SERVERCERT).getContent()

    ## should be ca's public key from sudo mv cacert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/?
    certificateAuthority = Certificate.loadPEM(pemBytes)
    myCertificate = PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(pemBytes)
    serverEndpoint = SSL4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 4321, myCertificate.options(certificateAuthority))
    serverEndpoint.listen(Factory.forProtocol(ReportWhichClient))
    return Deferred()

react(main, [])
##------------------------------- Server End -------------------------------##
```

Client:

```
##---------------------------- Client function -----------------------------##
##Main key reading class
@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor, name):
    ## Client private key
    pem = FilePath(name.encode("client1.key.pem").getContent()
    #CA public key
    caPem = FilePath(b"ca.cert.pem").getContent()

    clientEndpoint = SSL4ClientEndpoint(
        reactor, u"localhost", 4321,
        optionsForClientTLS(u"Nameless CA", Certificate.loadPEM(caPem),
                            PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(pem)),
    )

    proto = yield clientEndpoint.connect(Factory.forProtocol(SendAnyData))
    yield proto.deferred

import sys
react(main, sys.argv[1:])
##-------------------------- Client function End ---------------------------##
```

Comment: I don't know Python, but I do know OpenSSL. Based on `'SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE', 'no certificate returned'`, did you tell the server to send the list of X509 common names used for client authentication? To do it purely in OpenSSL, you need to call `SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list` at the server to trigger it. Did you do the equivalent in Python? If so, did the client return a certificate? See this related question: [Allow connections only by client with certificates signed by organizational CA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30134231).

Comment: How did you make out here?

Comment: I actually got it set up with a few minor modifications and using easy-rsa instead of openssl, i'm pretty sure if i port everything back to openssl, my only issue would be my extendedKeyUsage key, ithink the SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list is built into sslserverendpoints option call. your comment really did help in pointing me in the right direction, thank you =D

Comment: I already answered pretty much this same question over on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677455/use-tls-and-python-for-authentication/28682511#28682511